# Check if element with XPath exists

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium web driver with firefox driver. I have to check if this element is in the page using its XPath so I can continue to the next step but I don't know how to do it.

```
//*[@id='view_container']/form/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]

if (idk what i have to write here)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id='view_container']/form/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]"));

    // if we found xpath
} 
else
{   
    // if don't find xpath 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below-

```
try
{
    if(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id='view_container']/form/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]")).Displayed)
    {
    // if we found xpath
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // if don't find xpath
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152940/discussion-on-answer-by-kapil-i-need-about-if-c-if-there-is-a-xpath-or-not). If you are still having a problem, update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FindElements` and check if there are any in the returned collection. This will prevent an exception in case the element doesn't exists

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//[@id='view_container']/form/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]"));
if (elements.Count > 0)
{
     // found       
}
```

And to use the elements use index `elements[0]`.